# Global ~/.gitignore not working for one specific repo

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a .gitignore in my home folder containing:

```
.DS_Store
*sublime*
...etc...
```

Displaying the git config gives me this:

```
core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore
```

Everything gets ignored nicely in every project repository I'm working with. Except for one that I've cloned from a third party company we're collaborating with. Sublime files, .DS_Store files, ... keep popping up unless I define them in the local .gitignore of the repository. Not a major problem, but annoying.

What could be causing this? 
Could there be specific git settings in the cloned repo that override my settings?

I'm using Tower, btw, not that I think it really matters ;)

Comment: Was there an existing `.gitignore` in the third party repository? What did it contain? Remember that `.gitignore` can be at any level in a repo, not only at the root of it. Perhaps there is a `.gitignore` there with a negative pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the local `.gitignore` file "unignores" some of the patterns you specified in your global `.gitignore`. Look through the local one for any patterns that start with an exclamation point; that is the "unignore" operator. For example, `!*` would unignore all files.

Comment: It was indeed a negative pattern !* in the local .gitignore. Upvotes for everyone! ;)

Comment: What is global `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the local .gitignore overrides the global one. You can either remove the other .gitignore and let your system use the one that you declared.

Comment: Where is it located?

Comment: You can have it in the root folder of the repository.

Comment: I mean global = in the root folder, local = in a specific folder under root.